# How to find the unique list entries in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has the movie title along with the different genres that it falls under. Each movie has more than one genre. Hence, for the entire dataset I want to find the total number of unique genres that are present.

I am not able to use `df.unique()` as it is a list in each column of the DataFrame itself.

```
movieId title   genres
0   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1   2   Jumanji (1995)  Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2   3   Grumpier Old Men (1995) Comedy|Romance
3   4   Waiting to Exhale (1995)    Comedy|Drama|Romance
4   5   Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy
5   6   Heat (1995) Action|Crime|Thriller
6   7   Sabrina (1995)  Comedy|Romance
7   8   Tom and Huck (1995) Adventure|Children
8   9   Sudden Death (1995) Action
9   10  GoldenEye (1995)    Action|Adventure|Thriller
10  11  American President, The (1995)  Comedy|Drama|Romance
11  12  Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995)  Comedy|Horror
12  13  Balto (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children
13  14  Nixon (1995)    Drama
14  15  Cutthroat Island (1995) Action|Adventure|Romance
15  16  Casino (1995)   Crime|Drama
16  17  Sense and Sensibility (1995)    Drama|Romance
17  18  Four Rooms (1995)   Comedy
18  19  Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)   Comedy
19  20  Money Train (1995)  Action|Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller
20  21  Get Shorty (1995)   Comedy|Crime|Thriller
21  22  Copycat (1995)  Crime|Drama|Horror|Mystery|Thriller
22  23  Assassins (1995)    Action|Crime|Thriller
23  24  Powder (1995)   Drama|Sci-Fi
24  25  Leaving Las Vegas (1995)    Drama|Romance
25  26  Othello (1995)  Drama
26  27  Now and Then (1995) Children|Drama
27  28  Persuasion (1995)   Drama|Romance
28  29  City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants p...
```

This is the dataset for movies.

Under the genres column I want to split `Action|Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller` into Action, Comedy, Crime, Drama, Thriller.

Also for the entire dataset which is as a DataFrame now, I want to find the unique genres.

Comment: Did you try to first collect all the genres columns into one array, then call the .unique()?

Comment: No, not yet. I am pretty new to python, hence I am not familiar with that. I will try it.

Comment: I tried this, it did work. But it just took time to run. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! Anyhow AkshayNevrekar answer seems to be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach:

```
temp = df.genres.str.split("|").tolist() # this will return a list of lists for all the genres
import functools
import operator

unique_genres = set(functools.reduce(operator.concat, temp)) #this will flatten the list of lists and ultimately call the set to get the unique genres. Use len to get the number of unique genres afterwards
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':['Toy Story (1995)','Jumanji (1995)','Grumpier Old Men (1995)'],
                            'genres':['Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy','Adventure|Children|Fantasy','Comedy|Romance']})


a = list(set([y for x in df['genres'] for y in x.split('|')]))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['Animation', 'Comedy', 'Children', 'Fantasy', 'Adventure', 'Romance']
```

Comment: This also worked great. But the one given by ashish14 seemed to be faster. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
df = pda.read_csv('movies.csv')
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x.strip().split('|'))
df['count'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda y: len(y))
print(df)

OUTPUT :

   movie   Id  ...                                             genres count
     0    1  ...  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]     5
     1    2  ...                     [Adventure, Children, Fantasy]     3
     2    3  ...                                  [Comedy, Romance]     2
     3    4  ...                           [Comedy, Drama, Romance]     3
     4    5  ...                                           [Comedy]     1
     5    6  ...                          [Action, Crime, Thriller]     3
```